# Interrupt Oracle Database Delete and Update Row using Trigger

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two tables (T1 & T2), with T2.T1_ID referencing T1.ID. I'm trying to act on a row delete operation in T1 using a trigger such that if there are no references to the T1 row in T2, then the T1 row is deleted. Otherwise, it simply sets a flag value on the HIDDEN column of the T1 row. I've tried doing this by checking T2 for matching references and if so, I raise an exception which cancels the delete and attempts to set the flag instead, but it doesn't seem to work. When compiling the trigger, I get an error of

> "ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"

Which I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that I'm attempting to change data during a delete operation. I've tried doing something similar with an "after delete" trigger with similar issues. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
create table "T1" (
  "ID" number not null enable,
  "HIDDEN" number,
  constraint "T1_PK" primary key ("ID")
);

create table "T2" (
  "T1_ID" number not null enable,
  "VAL" number,
  constraint "T2_FK1" foreign key ("T1_ID") references "T1" ("ID") enable
);

create or replace trigger "BD_T1"
  before delete on "T1"
  for each row
declare
  cnt NUMBER;
  records_found EXCEPTION;    
begin   
  select count(*) into cnt from T2 where T1_ID = :OLD."ID";
  if cnt > 0 then
    RAISE records_found;
  end if;
exception
  when records_found then
    :NEW."HIDDEN" := 1; -- set hidden flag and abort delete operation
end;

insert into T1 ("ID") values (1);
insert into T1 ("ID") values (2);

insert into T2 ("T1_ID", "VAL") values (1, 100);
insert into T2 ("T1_ID", "VAL") values (1, 200);

select * from T1;
delete from T1 where ID = 2; --no references so row deleted
select * from T2;
delete from T1 where ID = 1; -- references found so abort delete and set     hidden flag`
```

Comment: You don't want to raise an exception or have a trigger if child records are found. Oracle will raise `ORA-02292 Constraint violation - child records found ` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your trigger is attempting the change a DELETE statement into an UPDATE statement. You cannot do this! However, you can accomplish what you need by eliminating the trigger altogether ands replacing the DELETE statement with a MERGE statement with the delete option. Try:

```
merge into t1
  using (select 1 t1id from dual
         union all 
         select 2 t1id from dual) t
  on (t1.id = t.t1id) 
  when matched then 
      update set t1.hidden = 1 
      delete where not exists 
             (select null from t2 where t2.t1_id = t1id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your trigger is attempting the change a DELETE statement into an UPDATE statement. You cannot do this! However, you can accomplish what you need by eliminating the trigger altogether ands replacing the DELETE statement with a MERGE statement with the delete option. Try:

```
merge into t1
  using (select 1 t1id from dual
         union all 
         select 2 t1id from dual) t
  on (t1.id = t.t1id) 
  when matched then 
      update set t1.hidden = 1 
      delete where not exists 
             (select null from t2 where t2.t1_id = t1id);
```